I need help to understand Income tax will be applicable if working in Saudi Arabia and salary transfer to Indian account
I am working in Saudi Arabia and my salary is getting credited into Indian Bank Account and the account is regular not NRI. So, I'll be eligible to pay Income tax on my earnings as per taxation rule in India or it will be barred off.
Kindly respond this might be helpful for me.

If the salary is getting credited in Indian bank account, it is taxable as per Indian tax law. Ideally you should get it credited in a bank account in Saudi Arabia & then remit it back to India. In that case, income would not be taxable. You can check provisions of India Saudi DTAA if available for any exemption. As per FEMA, you need to convert account to NRO so please do it withut delay.

No. I am assuming you are working in Saudi Arabia with a work visa, then your regular account will automatically become an NRI account. The Saudi tex system will be imposed on you as you are using their infrastructure and living in their country. You will pay income tax to Saudi Arabia which would be around 1.4%.

Do you have any citation for "regular account will automatically become an NRI account"? How does the bank even know that the account owner is or has become an NRI? Many people never inform their banks that they are NRIs and continue using their address in India (or parents' address or wife's address etc) for their banking needs in India.  Indeed, what is a "NRI account"? The usual terminology is NRE account and NRO account.

You will acquire a work visa. So the Indian Government will know about it. Or you can go to the nearest branch of your bank to verify once. If yes then continuee with the process. If not, which I think won't happen, you can change according to the procedure dictated.
